# Is there an easier way of finding cpp executable in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've started programming in c++ and I recently switched from a text editor to visual studio's ide, and I found out how to compile a single hello world. But it takes a bit to actually find the executable which is in a mess of folders full of a bunch of different files.

Is there just an easier way to find the file? Or change where the file is compiled at?

Comment: Are you taking about VSCode or Visual Studio Community / Pro / Enterprise. VSCode is a very different product from Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm talking about visual studio community 2022

Comment: By default in Visual Studio Community / Pro / Enterprise you will have a Debug folder that is inside the same folder as your project. Inside this debug folder you should have your executable. For release it will be named Release. When running your code the default working directory will be this root folder that contains the project file so that in Debug mode and Release mode you can put your data file in the same location. I say by default in all of this because as a user you have the option to change all of these settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual Studio (not code), go to the Project menu, then to <Project_name> properties. In the popup window go to Configuration properties/General, you will find the output directory.

Plan B: when building your solution, the full path of the exe is displayed in the console output.

Comment: Wow I didn't see that I just thought is was the compiler, thanks man :D

Comment: I saw it is $(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration), and it corresponds to ProjectName/x64/Debug on my PC. I understand Platform corresponds to x64 but why does Configuration corresponds to Debug? Btw where can I find information of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Output Directory in project settings. But generally, you don't even need to care. Just hit "F5" to launch your application (in debugger) or "CTRL+F5" to launch without the debugger.

Comment: I know that and I love that I can just run code super easily, but I want the executable to give to other people so they can run it and such.

Comment: @paxxous also checkout cool stuff like release configurations since you are new to using visual studio. You can create special preprocessor definitions on different configurations of your project. For example, you could create a logging macro which only logs stuff when in debug mode and not when it is built in release config

Comment: @PMF Thanks, It's weird jumping from a simplistic text editor to an ide.

Comment: @paxxous Yea, that's for sure. But when the projects grow larger, so do the tools. You wouldn't want to build and maintain a car just with a single screwdriver, I presume.